# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView After Progaurd enabled

Tags: android, material-design

My app crashes when I run my app after minifyEnabled true.

The error I am getting after running the app is this

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.instant/com.example.instant.activity.IntroActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.example.instant:layout/activity_intro: Binary XML file line #56 in com.example.instant:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3304)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.example.instant:layout/activity_intro: Binary XML file line #56 in com.example.instant:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56 in com.example.instant:layout/activity_intro: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

**This is my progaurd file**

```
        -keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
        -keep class com.smsdaakindia.instantpay.utils.** { *; }
        -keep class com.smsdaakindia.instantpay.model.** { *; }
        -keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }
        #-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**

        #Material design
        #-dontnote com.google.android.material.**

        -dontwarn androidx.**
        -keep class androidx.** { *; }
        -keep interface androidx.** { *; }

        -dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
        -dontnote com.google.android.material.**

        -dontwarn androidx.**
        -keep class androidx.** { *; }
        -keep interface androidx.** { *; }

        # RETRO LAMBDA
        -dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*

        # RETROFIT RULES
        -keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
        -keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
        -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
        -keep class retrofit.** { *; }
        -keepclasseswithmembers class * {@retrofit.http.* <methods>;}
        -keep interface retrofit.** { *;}
        -keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }
        -dontwarn rx.**
        -dontwarn retrofit.**

        -keep class com.google.gson.* { *; }
        -keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }
        -keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }
        -keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }
        -keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
        -keep class retrofit.* { *; }

        -keepattributes Signature
        -keepattributes *Annotation*

        -keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

This is my dependency`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="bottomNavigationHandler"
            type="com.example.instant.viewmodel.BottomNavigationHandler" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/navigationParent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navigationParent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.01dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
                    android:background="@color/grey_100"
                    android:elevation="1dp" />


                <!--                <include-->
                <!--                    layout="@layout/bottom_bar"-->
                <!--                    android:id="@+id/bottom" />-->


                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_view"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{bottomNavigationHandler::onNavigationClick}"
                    app:elevation="0dp"/>

                <!--                <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView-->
                <!--                    android:id="@+id/navigation"-->
                <!--                    android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--                    android:layout_height="52dp"-->
                <!--                    android:background="@color/lightgrey"-->
                <!--                    android:visibility="visible"-->
                <!--                    android:showAsAction="always|withText"-->
                <!--                    app:itemBackground="@color/lightlightgrey"-->
                <!--                    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_view"-->
                <!--                    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextStyleBNV"-->
                <!--                    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_view"-->
                <!--                    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"-->
                <!--                    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"-->
                <!--                    app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{bottomNavigationHandler::onNavigationClick}" />-->

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log?

Comment: Please check i have edited the error log.If anything else is required please let me know.

Comment: Please upload IntroActivity layout(xml) file as well

Comment: please check my intro file

Comment: remove `app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_view"` line and try

Comment: tried it but the app is still getting crashed

Comment: If the issue is still persist then disable the proguard for material components. I don't think the issue is with proguard because it applies only in release mode.